# How to use Chinese/English keyboard in Alpine Linux

Tags: keyboard-layout, thinkpad, input-method, alpine-linux

I recently replaced the US keyboard on my Thinkpad X200, with one that is a  mixed English / Chinese keyboard (An example image of it can be seen [here](https://www.4keyboard.com/269/chinese-chinese-english-non-transparent-keyboard-stickers.jpg)). Currently it is functioning as an impeccable replacement for my US keyboard, however, I am wondering how to set up my computer to be able to type the Chinese glyphs as well.

I am *not* looking for the ability to type Chinese using pinyin, I am looking for a method of typing the glyphs appearing on my keys. I assume that this uses perhaps the alt-gr or Fn key in combination with another key (Which, I just noticed, my keyboard does not have!), this obviously does not currently work, however.

So far I have looked at the keyboard geometry files, but it does not appear that there is a geometry file for my keyboard (there's a generic 'thinkpad' one, which contains `'common'`, `'us'`, `'intl'`, `'60'`, none of which seem to cover my specific variant).

I tried using some of the commands available on the Arch Linux wiki page for keyboard configuration, but they are SystemD-centric and therefore do not work on Alpine Linux.

EDIT: After some further digging I noticed that the 'cn' layout appears to be approximately what I want. However, after I set it using xkbmap (specifically `setxbkmap -model thnkpad -layout cn`) and attempting to type the keys (with various modifiers applied), nothing happens.

Comment: Which OS? you will probably need to install a language pack, then to enable the keyboard layout, and set a key or button to allow you to switch.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor `"therefore do not work on Alpine Linux."`

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor could you point me to something that explains the first step better? I've attempted to switch keyboard layout with setxkbmap and it appears to do nothing.

Comment: That's a keyboard with Zhuyin and hints for two input methods on the engravings: Cangjie and Dayi.  In the latter, the symbols are only _parts_ of a character.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I have told you twice, although I probably should have been explicit. I am using Alpine Linux.

Comment: Sorry I did not see the **one** (the other times were at least 4 hours after I asked) comment that told me the OS. I probably ignored it because it did not make sense. “"therefore do not work on Alpine Linux."” (Why are you telling me not to use Alpine Linux?).

Comment: It makes sense if one reads the "they" earlier in the sentence.  (-: